# How do I make three tables in one div not overlap on resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I have three tables(fixed-data-table from React) inside a panel. It works well - but on smaller resolutions, the three tables will overlap with each other. Is there a way to make them scalable?

Here's the code where the tables are returned:

```
return (
   <div>
      <div style = {{position: "absolute", marginTop: "15%", top: "0px", left: "0px", marginLeft: "3%"}}>
         <Table
             height={35 + ((18) * 30)}
             width={280}
             rowsCount={firstTable.length}
             rowHeight={30}
             headerHeight={30}>
             <Column
                header={<Cell>First</Cell>}
                cell={<TextCell data={firstTable} col="first" />}
                width={70}
             />
             <Column
                header={<Cell>Second</Cell>}
                cell={<TextCell data={firstTable} col="second" />}
                width={105}
             />
             <Column
                header={<Cell>Third</Cell>}
                cell={<TextCell data={firstTable} col="third" />}
                width={105}
             />
         </Table>
      </div>
      <div style = {{position: "absolute", marginTop: "15%", top: "0px", right: "0px", marginRight: "3%" }}>
         <Table
             height={35 + ((secondTable.length) * 30)}
             width={280}
             rowsCount={secondTable.length}
             rowHeight={30}
             headerHeight={30}>
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>First</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={secondTable} col="first" />}
                 width={70}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>Second</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={secondTable} col="respBytes" />}
                 width={105}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>third</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={secondTable} col="third" />}
                 width={105}
             />
         </Table>
     </div>
     <div style = {{position: "absolute", marginBottom: "10%", bottom: "0px", right: "0", marginRight: "3%" }}>
         <Table
             height={35 + ((thirdTable.length) * 30)}
             width={280}
             rowsCount={thirdTable.length}
             rowHeight={30}
             headerHeight={30}>
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>first</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={thirdTable} col="first" />}
                 width={70}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>second</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={thirdTable} col="second" />}
                 width={105}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>third</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={thirdTable} col="third" />}
                 width={105}
             />
        </Table>
    </div>
</div>
```

They're called in another file as, using react-grid-layout as such:

```
<div key={'nicetable'} className = "panel">
    <div className="chart-title">
        <h3 style={{cursor: "pointer", textAlign: "center"}}>Three tables!</h3>
    </div>
    <tableExample data={this.state.data.threetabledata } />
</div>
```

It displays fine on a 4k monitor but the issue is that the tables themselves don't scale, so f.e. on a 1080p resolution, they'd just clutter over one another. Since I'm using `React-grid-layout` where you can resize the respective panels, scalability with resolution is desired since users can alter the panel size themselves. Right now, if you make the panel small, the tables will overlap each other.

How do I make them resize to the parent div(the resizable panel)?

I'm fine with the table scaling font and width/height of everything, as that would even be nicer for lower resolution monitors.

Comment: If I don't use the styling, the tables will, per default, overlap with each other. So I don't think that's the solution. Right now, it pushes them into three different corners?

Comment: Generally flexbox is very good for responsive content. The flexbox items do not overlap each other (of course cou could do that if you like...). Sometimes I use flexbox even for tables, to make the table able to change the layout if it becomes very small.

Comment: I'll look into flexbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap for the div . Here is the code. Use as it is.Hope it works for you :-) .

`return (
   <div>
      <div  className="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style = {{position: "absolute", marginTop: "15%", top: "0px", left: "0px", marginLeft: "3%"}}>
         <Table
             height={35 + ((18) * 30)}
             width={280}
             rowsCount={firstTable.length}
             rowHeight={30}
             headerHeight={30}>
             <Column
                header={<Cell>First</Cell>}
                cell={<TextCell data={firstTable} col="first" />}
                width={70}
             />
             <Column
                header={<Cell>Second</Cell>}
                cell={<TextCell data={firstTable} col="second" />}
                width={105}
             />
             <Column
                header={<Cell>Third</Cell>}
                cell={<TextCell data={firstTable} col="third" />}
                width={105}
             />
         </Table>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style = {{position: "absolute", marginTop: "15%", top: "0px", right: "0px", marginRight: "3%" }}>
         <Table
             height={35 + ((secondTable.length) * 30)}
             width={280}
             rowsCount={secondTable.length}
             rowHeight={30}
             headerHeight={30}>
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>First</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={secondTable} col="first" />}
                 width={70}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>Second</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={secondTable} col="respBytes" />}
                 width={105}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>third</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={secondTable} col="third" />}
                 width={105}
             />
         </Table>
     </div>
     <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style = {{position: "absolute", marginBottom: "10%", bottom: "0px", right: "0", marginRight: "3%" }}>
         <Table
             height={35 + ((thirdTable.length) * 30)}
             width={280}
             rowsCount={thirdTable.length}
             rowHeight={30}
             headerHeight={30}>
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>first</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={thirdTable} col="first" />}
                 width={70}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>second</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={thirdTable} col="second" />}
                 width={105}
             />
             <Column
                 header={<Cell>third</Cell>}
                 cell={<TextCell data={thirdTable} col="third" />}
                 width={105}
             />
        </Table>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: They still overlap when making the grid smaller(or browser) using that example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc` in your table containers:

```
div {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: You have to add a bit more detail. Where?